# Web Audio choppy sound playing chunks of PCM stream

Tags: javascript, html, audio, audiocontext

I am running in to an issue playing raw PCM data using Web Audio API.  I receive raw PCM data via a web socket and create buffers and queue them up with AudioContext.createBufferSource.  The PCM data is correct, however the timing for the audio is off.

In the receive function I buffer until I have about 1 second of audio and then play it.  Subsequent  receives are queued as soon as they come in.  This ensure that the audio chunks are queued before the player gets to that time.  Here is the queuing function: http://pastebin.com/KXn6kEYw

Here is example output showing that audio chunks are processed before the previous chunks are done playing:

```
 Current time: 2.449705215419501
 Duration: 0.7964172335600908
 Play at: 2.499705215419501 End at: 3.2961224489795917

 Current time: 2.9257142857142857
 Duration: 0.58
 Play at: 3.2961224489795917 End at: 3.876122448979592

 Current time: 3.3436734693877552
 Duration: 0.58
 Play at: 3.876122448979592 End at: 4.456122448979592

 Current time: 3.645532879818594
 Duration: 0.58
 Play at: 4.456122448979592 End at: 5.036122448979592

 Current time: 3.982222222222222
 Duration: 0.58
 Play at: 5.036122448979592 End at: 5.616122448979592
```

Here is an example of the choppy audio: http://protological.com/plfiles/choppy.mp3

It appears that all the audio data is being played, just with a gap between segments

One thing that is interesting is the gap in the audio is about the same length of time as the audio chunk. Smaller segments have smaller gaps, almost as if the audio is playing for 2x the duration.

Comment: The error was in the PCM processing, not the Web Audio API.  The PCM data is 16bits long, so .length of the buffer is really 2*Samples.  I was making a buffer .length long, thus 2x what it should be.  The posted audio play function works.  There is some slight static as the different clips are played but not choppy